# \includemedia does not play video but remains blank (Part 2)

Tags: pdf, media9, video

I am having a similar issue to a prior forum ([\includemedia does not play video but remains blank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94191/includemedia-does-not-play-video-but-remains-blank#)).

I would like to have a video in my pdf that plays when you click on it. When the video is not playing it should show a figure. When I compile my pdf I do get a figure that I can click on, but it turns blank when I click on it, and no video plays. I don't get any errors either. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[]{media9}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[activate=pageopen, width=1.0\textwidth, addresource=./Videos/myVideoH.mp4, flashvars={source=./Videos/myVideoH.mp4}]{\includegraphics{./pathCB.png}}{VPlayer9.swf} 
\end{document}
```

I believe I took into account all the suggestions mentioned in the prior forum. For instance, I have the same issue whether I use {VPlayer9.swf} or {VPlayer.swf}. Moreover, I downloaded a new .mp4 file that was listed as codec h.264, and the problem persisted. Finally, I converted the .mp4 file to .flv, and still the problem persisted.

In all these cases, upon running pdflatex, I received no error to produce the .pdf file, and the image showed up with a play button superimposed, but I could not click on the image and begin the video.

Along the same lines, I am using a stock video now to get the general syntax working. However, I would ultimately like to record my own video and use that instead. So, if this problem is because of pickiness of the format of the video being used, I would simultaneously be very grateful to hear any advice about how I should record my video to keep the syntax working.

(I am using OS X 10.9.5.)

Thank you for any of your advice!

Comment: Did you try appending `&autoPlay=true` to the `flashvars` option, rather than `activate=pageopen`?

Comment: @AFeldman Thank you! I had also tried that! I tried it again, so my syntax looks like (\includemedia[width=1.0\textwidth, addresource=./Videos/myVideoH.mp4, flashvars={&autoPlay=true, source=./Videos/myVideoH.mp4}]{\includegraphics{./pathCB.png}}{VPlayer9.swf}). I still have the same problem. No error message, picture is there, but movie will not play.

Comment: Looks like you pre-pended &autoPlay=true instead of appending it. I don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: @AFeldman Thanks for your input! I tried appending it instead (\includemedia[width=1.0\textwidth, addresource=./Videos/myVideoH.mp4, flashvars={source=./Videos/myVideoH.mp4, &autoPlay=true}]{\includegraphics{./pathCB.png}}{VPlayer9.swf}), but I still have the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: The PDF must be opened in Acrobat Reader (Apple Preview or how it is called is not enough) and you also need Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you so much! I did download for free Acrobat Reader, and then it worked. So, if I am sharing the .pdf with others (and they could be using Mac/ PC/ etc), should I include a note that advises them to open it in Acrobat Reader? In other words, do you believe this would also work on PC etc? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Maybe a good idea. Tell them to use a recent (version >= 9) Acrobat Reader on Windows or Max OS X. On mobile devices though, the videos don't play, unfortunately.